# Trying to add/fetch data in/from database using AngularJS with REST API in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest

I am trying to add data in database using AngularJS with REST API in PHP. But doing so I am getting an error,

> POST http://localhost/spa/sp-cart/server_scripts/rest_api.php 404 (Not Found)

Here are my codes,

signup.html

```
<div class="container main">
<!--<div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="wishToCart">{{duplicateData}}</div>-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="account-wall">
            <form action="" method="">
                <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="register">
                        <div class="form-signin">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name ..." required autofocus>
                            <input type="email" ng-model="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Emaill Address ..." required>
                            <input type="password" ng-model="userpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password ..." required>
                            <button ng-click="signup()" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" value="Sign Up">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('cartApp.signup.controllers', []).
controller('SignupController',
['$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope, $http) {

        $log.log('inside login controller');

        $scope.signup = function () {
            $log.log('signup data stored');
            $http.post('../server_scripts/rest_api.php',
            { 'username': $scope.username,
                'email': $scope.useremail,
                'password': $scope.userpassword
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                $log.log('Data Insert Error');
            });
        }

    }
]);
```

For REST API I am using the code from the following link (made necessary changes to match my database name, password and username)

[Creating a simple REST API in PHP](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/)

Please help me understand the main problem for which I am getting the 404 error for my rest_api.php file. I have the correct path.

Thank you in advance.

Note: I am novice to data inserting in database. Please help me step by step.

Comment: this means path to your php file is incorrect please check whether the file is exist

Comment: I have cross checked, but unfortunately the file path is correct. I have my PHP file in that path. I have no clue why I am getting a 404 for it.